# What is the right way to specify the image source in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use a background image for a window in WPF. I am intending to use ImageBrush. I have the image in the root folder and also in the Assets folder.

I found many answers in StackOverflow to provide the URI but all seems to fail.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Content = new MainPage();

    Image image = new Image
    {
        //Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyWPFApp;component/myimage.jpg"))           // Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
        //Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyWPFApp;component/Assets/myimage.jpg"))    // Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
        //Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyWPFApp;/Assets/myimage.jpg"))             // Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

        //Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\myimage.jpg", UriKind.Relative))                      // Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).
        //Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Assets\myimage.jpg", UriKind.Relative))               // Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

        //Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://MyWPFApp:,,,/myimage.jpg"))           // The URI prefix is not recognized

    };
    MyBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
}
```

What are the correct formats and when should I use the above formats?

P.S: these are working

```
    <ImageBrush x:Name="MyBrush" Opacity="0.3" ImageSource="/Assets/myimage.jpg"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ImageBrush x:Name="MyBrush" Opacity="0.3" ImageSource="/myimage.jpg"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Comment: Note that the Image element is redundant. Simply assign the BitmapImage directly to the ImageBrush's ImageSource property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a pack url if you are assigning the image from the code behind

```
Image image; // ...
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/logo.png"));
```

You can do some independent research on what this url should be, but most likely will be something similar to this for your case:

`pack://application:,,,/MyWPFApp;component/Assets/myimage.jpg`

Comment: Are these valid in any scenarios Uri("/MyWPFApp;component/myimage.jpg"), Uri(@"\Assets\myimage.jpg", UriKind.Relative)

Comment: The important point is that (in contrast to XAML) in code behind it is required to write a full Pack URI, including the prefix. It is also necessary to set the Build Action of the image file to Resource.